# Read file in Octave

Tags: octave, scanf

I need to read a data file into Octave that may have different numbers of
elements in each line, while retaining the line separation.

For example, read in:

```
1 2 3 4 5  
6 7 8 9  
1 2 3  
4 5 6 7 8
```

How can I use `scanf` to obtain something like:

```
 1 2 3 4 5  
 6 7 8 9 0  
 1 2 3 0 0  
 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: You might try `fgetl` instead – [see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Line_002dOriented-Input.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually is really easy using the function `dlmread(file)`

Answer (score 0):

Your crosspost on the help mailinglist was answered from Przemek: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.octave.general/57521

```
dlmread("filename")
```

will do what you want.